# Spoofing an IP using a node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a proxy for Minecraft servers, and would like to be able to forward the original user's IP address. The issue is, through the 'proxy', the proxy's IP is seen. I know this is the idea behind proxies, but I would like to keep the original sender's IP, and forward them to another IP.

My current code;

```
var net = require('net');

var sourceport = 25555;
var destport = 25565;

function bufferTrim(buf, trm){
    var len = buf.length;
    return buf.slice(0, len-trm);
}

net.createServer(function(s)
{
    var buff = "";
    var connected = false;
    var cli = net.createConnection(destport);

    s.on('data', function(d) {
        var hex = d.toString('hex').substr(0,2);
        if (connected)
        {
            if (hex == "fe")
            {
                var sName = "Faker";
                var sMaxSlots = "8";
                var sUsedSlots = "0";
                s.write(bufferTrim(new Buffer(String.fromCharCode(0xFF).concat(String.fromCharCode(sName.length + sMaxSlots.length + sUsedSlots.length + 2)).concat(sName).concat(String.fromCharCode(0xA7)).concat(sUsedSlots).concat(String.fromCharCode(0xA7)).concat(sMaxSlots), 'ucs2'), 1));
            } else {
                cli.write(d);
            }
        } else {
            buff += d.toString();
        }
    });

    cli.on('connect', function() {
        connected = true;
        cli.write(buff);
    });
    cli.pipe(s);
}).listen(sourceport);
```

Comment: Given how TCP/IP works, I believe this is not possible. You can't spoof an IP address on the IP layer, and I believe this address is what the server sees, not something higher-level.

Comment: Ah, ok. It's this post that led me to believe it's possible; http://stackoverflow.com/a/12736911/1209046
Mainly because packets would be rerouted directly to them

Comment: You can advertise a "desired" IP-address via a semi-standard HTTP header, but you can't make your proxy invisible. Google `X-FORWARDED-FOR` if that's what I think.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think Minecraft looks for that header in it's protocol.

Comment: As the linked answer says, if you send an IP packet with a foreign source IP address, you'll never get the response. The one whose address you use would, and he would be very confused.

Comment: I just want my script to redirect a user to another server, is there a way without using a proxy and faking the IP?

Comment: only if the protocol supports that. HTTP does. If said protocol doesn't you'll have to forward eeeverything (in both directions, unless the server spoofs _your_ sender address (yuck) and both <del>modify</del> rape the TCP protocol).