# Exchange Data between two webroles over an Https endpoint

Tags: ssl, azure, https, endpoint, restriction

I have two webroles, without a WCF communication between them (this is  intentionally)

Communication and authentification is one sided. Thus one webrole allways sends requests and the other one  allways accepts requests.

To make sure said  controller only accepts requests from  the other webrole we want to use an ssl certificate.

i installed the certificate -  and iam now able to make https requests to said controller.
however this is now active for the whole webrole.

In the final version users should be able to connect to the webrole over https with a global trust certificate  for obvious security reasons.
This would require one azure https endpoint.
another endpoint then would be needed for our internal communication ( with our internal certificate).

But: How to restrict the controller which is  used only for internal  communication to its specified https request? (based on the interrnal certificate)
On the other hand how do i validate on the client side (  the webrole which makes the request) that said  certificate was valid ?

Is there a better way to ensure a secure communication between two webroles? maybe using internal endpoints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at defining internal endpoints for the role-to-role communication. Something like this should work:

```
<NetworkTrafficRules>
  <OnlyAllowTrafficTo>
    <Destinations>
      <RoleEndpoint endpointName="InternalTCP2" roleName="WorkerRole1"/>
    </Destinations>
    <AllowAllTraffic/>
    <WhenSource matches="AnyRule">
      <FromRole roleName="WebRole1"/>
    </WhenSource>
  </OnlyAllowTrafficTo>
</NetworkTrafficRules>
```

If you're communicating between roles through internal endpoints you shouldn't really need to invoke HTTPS.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i know about internal endpoints, what i couldnt find is any examples  for using these endpoints for actual communication. is it possible to just send a http request to that internal entpoint http://internalendpointip:port/action/controller?. 
If yes - how do i make sure that that cantroller is not callable through input entpoints?

Comment: Have look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180158.aspx Under the heading using internal end points there is an example of revealing the internal IP of a given endpoint. You should then be able to make HTTP, HTTPs and TCP calls via the internal IP. e.g http://10.0.0.X/mywebservice...

Comment: thanks, so its like i asumed. but this wont help with the security issue - if i make a http call to the internal endpoint somone can fake a http request to come from the webrole calling that internal endpoint. Thus there is no security at all - thus i would require https anyway. .to use an internal endpoint will then be obsolete

Comment: How can someone fake a call from an internal IP address?

Comment: Since there is no mechanism to encrypt the httprequest data i just could set "referrer" to that internal Ip and voila.
also, i solved my problem and i will provide code here tomorrow if everything goes as expected (which it nevar does ;)

Comment: You could but the response would go back to the internal IP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736872/can-someone-spoof-an-ip-address-to-any-number. Role-to-role communication in Azure is a common scenario and doesn't require HTTPs to be done securely. All the HTTPs will do is encrypt the communication between the roles but as this is done within the confines of your virtual network in Azure, it shouldn't be a concern.